# ASP.NET Login Controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

How can i know if a user is logged in or not by using code?
if i have implemented the asp.net login controls and want to create a page with a loginview in order to show for logged in users, data from a session using a label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If(Request.IsAuthenticated){
//user is logged-in - request is authenticated.
}
```

Alternatively if you are going to use LoginView, you can use [LoggedInTemplate](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/util/srcview.aspx?path=~/aspnet/samples/ctrlref/login/LoginViewBasic.src) whose content will only be displayed if user is authenticated.

If that doesn't answer your question you need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [LoginView control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview.aspx).